# Proguard - Proguard returned with error code 1

Tags: android, proguard

Recently integrated Pushwoosh library to my android app. It worked fine. But facing following error while export as signed application. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
 Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.MessageAlertReceiver: can't find superclass or interface com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageReceiver
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.PushAmazonIntentService: can't find superclass or interface com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageHandlerBase
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.PushAmazonIntentService$MessageAlertReceiver: can't find superclass or interface com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageReceiver
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.ADMRegistrar: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.ADMRegistrar: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.ADMRegistrar: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.MessageAlertReceiver: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageReceiver
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.MessageAlertReceiver: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageReceiver
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.PushAmazonIntentService: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageHandlerBase
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.PushAmazonIntentService: can't find referenced method 'android.content.Context getApplicationContext()' in class com.arellomobile.android.push.PushAmazonIntentService
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.PushAmazonIntentService: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageHandlerBase
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.PushAmazonIntentService$MessageAlertReceiver: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageReceiver
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.PushAmazonIntentService$MessageAlertReceiver: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageReceiver
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.registrar.PushRegistrarADM: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.registrar.PushRegistrarADM: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.registrar.PushRegistrarADM: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.registrar.PushRegistrarADM: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.registrar.PushRegistrarADM: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM
       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
 Warning: there were 17 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
 Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
          You may need to recompile them and try again.
          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
 java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
 Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
 proguard.ParseException: Expecting opening '{' at 'public' in line 22 of file 'D:\Android-pjt-build\Dec14\test\proguard-project.txt',
   included from argument number 4
    at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:678)
    at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseKeepClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:490)
    at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:139)
    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:484)
testProguard returned with error code 1. See console
testproguard.ParseException: Unknown option '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers.**' in line 24 of file 'D:\Android-pjt-build\Dec14\test\proguard-project.txt',
test  included from argument number 4
test    at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:191)
test    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:484)
 Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.MessageAlertReceiver: can't find superclass or interface com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageReceiver
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.PushAmazonIntentService: can't find superclass or interface com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageHandlerBase
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.PushAmazonIntentService$MessageAlertReceiver: can't find superclass or interface com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageReceiver
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.ADMRegistrar: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.ADMRegistrar: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.ADMRegistrar: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.MessageAlertReceiver: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageReceiver
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.MessageAlertReceiver: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageReceiver
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.PushAmazonIntentService: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageHandlerBase
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.PushAmazonIntentService: can't find referenced method 'android.content.Context getApplicationContext()' in class com.arellomobile.android.push.PushAmazonIntentService
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.PushAmazonIntentService: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageHandlerBase
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.PushAmazonIntentService$MessageAlertReceiver: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageReceiver
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.PushAmazonIntentService$MessageAlertReceiver: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageReceiver
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.registrar.PushRegistrarADM: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.registrar.PushRegistrarADM: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.registrar.PushRegistrarADM: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.registrar.PushRegistrarADM: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM
 Warning: com.arellomobile.android.push.registrar.PushRegistrarADM: can't find referenced class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM
       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
 Warning: there were 17 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
 Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
          You may need to recompile them and try again.
          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
 java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Comment: Have you read this message? It tells you what the problem is and gives some suggestions for fixing it. Start with that and ask again if you get stuck.

Comment: @HoboSapiens I tried by adding `-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers` as per suggestion. but still I am getting same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by adding this line in project.txt

```
-dontwarn com.arellomobile.android.push.**
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not obfuscate Pushwoosh classes, as well as com.arellomobile.android.*

Answer (score 1):

put this line in last line of proguard file

```
-dontwarn com.amazon.**
```